# RouteAttribute can't be found in System.Web.Http package

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've added the `ASP.NET web API self host` using the NuGet package manager to my project (a windows service project)
the Nuget added those libraries

- ASP.NET web API self host
- Json.NET
- Microsoft .NET framework 4 HTTP Client libraries
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client/Core libraries
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Self Host

When I try to add Route attribute I can't find it in the System.Web.Http. 
when i looked for this class in MSDN i saw its under this [package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

do i need to install another package or add another referance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to install this nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost`
use following in package manager console.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```

Comment: thanks man!. worked - kinda strange they didn't include this in the roiginal package